# Create a gradient button on 'react native' like this

Tags: react-native, gradient, linear-gradients

Need help creating a linear gradient like below

> Colors:"#8ce786" , "#5ab55e" ,"#146732"

[image: Button]

I tried to create the gradient button using **react-native-linear-gradient** library. But couldn't create the exact gradient.

Answer (score 0):

You can Export `SVG` format of your Image and use that in your project with import `react-native-svg` , then after that you can go to `svg to react native` site in [this](https://transform.tools/svg-to-react-native) link and create `js` file for your icon .